# Which open source ESB is recommended for JBoss 7.1?

Tags: jboss, esb, jboss7.x

JBossESB and Apache ServiceMix do not seem to be ready for JBoss 7.1

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Switchyard:

- http://www.jboss.org/switchyard

UPDATE: RedHat is going to replace JBossESB with SwitchYard:

- http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/feature/Red-Hat-makes-a-switch-SwitchYard-project-to-replace-JBoss-ESB